# How do you reuse an existing language server (LSP) in Java using LSP4J

Tags: java

We would like to create a headless client in Java that responds to changes in different pre-existing language servers. We are aware of the [instructions to start a language server](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls#user-content-running-from-the-command-line), and of the need to [Implement the Language Server](https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4j/blob/master/documentation/README.md#user-content-implement-your-language-server), but we have not found guidance on how this should be done for an existing server.

We believe that the `org.eclipse.lsp4j.services.LanguageServer` class is responsible for marshalling data for the server, but it is not obvious *how an existing server is exposed*.

There is [a list of implementations at the langserver.org](https://langserver.org/#implementations-server) website. Assuming I have been able to start one of these servers and have access to its stdin and stdout for client communication, **how** do I need to implement in lsp4j to attach it?

Comment: @aran
I don't see how the link you gave has anything to log with LSP4J. This is another implementation, but doesn't use LSP4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSP4J covers both client and server sides of the protocol.
It uses JSON-RPC to connect from client to server and vice-versa. Requests to server interface on client side are passed with JSON-RPC to the server implementation on server side. Notifications to client interface on server side are passed to the client implementation on client side.

In usual application, only client side of thing would be implemented, instantiating server interface via JSON-RPC (using using `org.eclipse.lsp4j.jsonrpc.Launcher.Builder`)

When implementing server interface, you can proxy requests to this remote server via Decorator pattern.